# OpenCV can't read image!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, image, include, opencv

I am using this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <cxtypes.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "dow2oc8.png" );
 cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 cvShowImage("Example1", img);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 cvReleaseImage( &img );
 cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
 return 0;
}
```

I took out the pound signs and carrets 
and I can't get it to read the image file, I have added the file to the project. 
What should I do next

Comment: Try using an absolute path like "c:\pics\dow2oc8.png" to see if it's a problem with your paths and not OpenCV

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using?Could you upload the image someplace? What kind of error did you get? **More information!!**

Comment: The var img can't get any info on the image as can't load image, using version 1.1 and tried absolute path still not working

Comment: the value for all parts of img   nSize CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that it's attempting to load the png file from a location other than where the png file actually is. It doesn't matter whether it's in the project or not - where is it on disk? Cause, with no path specified, it should probably be in the folder your executable is running from - which, if you added it to the project, it probably isn't.