# Read an image file in C/C++ into an array

Tags: c++, c, jpeg

How can I read a gray scale JPEG image file in C/C++ into a 2D array?

Comment: Is the documentation for libjpeg (http://www.ijg.org/) or whatever native API you have inadequate?

Comment: Don't forget to pick a correct answer for the three questions you've asked.

Comment: Check this thread out: [read and write image file](http://web.archive.org/web/20080625002549/http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic29852.htm). Also, have a look at [this other question at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533542/opencv-cant-read-image).

Answer (score 26):

If you decide to go for a minimal approach, without libpng/libjpeg dependencies, I suggest using `stb_image` and `stb_image_write`, found [here](https://github.com/nothings/stb).

It's as simple as it gets, you just need to place the header files `stb_image.h` and `stb_image_write.h` in your folder.

Here's the code that you need to read images:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

int main() {
    int width, height, bpp;

    uint8_t* rgb_image = stbi_load("image.png", &width, &height, &bpp, 3);

    stbi_image_free(rgb_image);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the code to write an image:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_write.h"

#define CHANNEL_NUM 3

int main() {
    int width = 800; 
    int height = 800;

    uint8_t* rgb_image;
    rgb_image = malloc(width*height*CHANNEL_NUM);

    // Write your code to populate rgb_image here

    stbi_write_png("image.png", width, height, CHANNEL_NUM, rgb_image, width*CHANNEL_NUM);

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile without flags or dependencies:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Other lightweight alternatives include:

- [lodepng](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng) to read and write png files
- [jpeg-compressor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jpeg-compressor/) to read and write jpeg files

Comment: I had to include the math.h library and link it while compiling (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor) or I would get an undefined reference to pow in the image library.

Comment: I know it's just an example but can you clarify what the magic number 3 means in the code?

Comment: @mattshu it's the number of channels (red, green, blue), maybe I should clarify this on my code, I'll do a edit.

Comment: How would I do something like this WITHOUT any odd libraries? I am not the author of the question, but I want to know how to this only using standard libraries like stdio.h Actually, how to do this ONLY using stdio.h?

Comment: STB developers ain't good.

Comment: How do I store the result in a 3D array, with the third dimension being the channel?

Answer (score 15):

You could write your own by looking at the [JPEG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

That said, try a pre-existing library like [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), or [Boost's GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html). Or for strictly JPEG's, [libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg). There is also the [CxImage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx) class on CodeProject.

Here's a [big list](http://www.mathtools.net/C_C__/Image_Processing/).

Comment: Boost.GIL does not work and is not being maintained.

Comment: Since C is allowed, I second libjpeg as the most lightweight solution. CImg and GIL are definitely easier syntax-wise--but also require libjpeg. You can trivially copy the data from a CImg object into some STL container or an array.

Comment: CImg also uses an LGPL-like license which is significantly more restrictive than libjpeg's BSD-like license.

Comment: @Tronic I see it still being maintained https://github.com/boostorg/gil

Answer (score 4):

Check out **Intel Open CV library** ...

Answer (score 3):

Try out the [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) library.  The [tutorial](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html) will help you get familiarized.  Once you have a CImg object, the [data()](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#1699472936b80a88d3fc8096975d21b2) function will give you access to the 2D pixel buffer array.

Comment: Actually it is modelled as a 4D pixel matrix, though a 2D grayscale image will have the depth and color dimension set to 1. Under the hood it is a 1D array of template type T.

Comment: I believe CImg requires libjpeg to load jpegs.

Answer (score 3):

[corona](http://corona.sourceforge.net/) is nice. From the tutorial:

```
corona::Image* image = corona::OpenImage("img.jpg", corona::PF_R8G8B8A8);
if (!image) {
  // error!
}

int width  = image->getWidth();
int height = image->getHeight();
void* pixels = image->getPixels();

// we're guaranteed that the first eight bits of every pixel is red,
// the next eight bits is green, and so on...
typedef unsigned char byte;
byte* p = (byte*)pixels;
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
  byte red   = *p++;
  byte green = *p++;
  byte blue  = *p++;
  byte alpha = *p++;
}
```

pixels would be a one dimensional array, but you could easily convert a given x and y position to a position in a 1D array. Something like pos = (y * width) + x

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Magick++ API](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).