# Undefined reference to `pow' and `floor'

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference

I'm trying to make a simple fibonacci calculator in C but when compiling `gcc` tells me that I'm missing the pow and floor functions. What's wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fibo(int n);

int main() {
        printf("Fib(4) = %d", fibo(4));
        return 0;
}

int fibo(int n) {
        double phi = 1.61803399;

        return (int)(floor((float)(pow(phi, n) / sqrt(5)) + .5f));
}
```

Output:

```
gab@testvm:~/work/c/fibo$ gcc fib.c -o fibo
/tmp/ccNSjm4q.o: In function `fibo':
fib.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `pow'
fib.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: As the floating point precision isn't infinite, this will give wrong answers for not so large values of `n`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to sqrt (or other mathematical functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248919/undefined-reference-to-sqrt-or-other-mathematical-functions)

Comment: It seems that an even easier solution exists, simply use g++ instead: g++ fib.c -o fibo

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You need to compile with the link flag `-lm`, like this:

```
gcc fib.c -lm -o fibo
```

This will tell gcc to link your code against the math lib. Just be sure to put the flag **after** the objects you want to link.

Comment: Could you please explain how to work out the letter to put after -l?

Comment: Look in /lib or /usr/lib. The libraries are all named `lib<name>.a` or `lib<name>.so` - it's the "<name>" you put after the `-l`. In this case, the math library is named `libm.so`, so we call it `-lm`.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been googling for the past 30 minutes and this is the first reference that said to link the libraries after the objects

Comment: You can also use LD_PRELOAD to tell ld runtime linker to include libm.so in the memory map and symbol table of the process, so these symbols get loaded and everything works as expected

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can anybody tell me why in case of codes with a few lines it's okay even if I do not include -lm while compiling ?

Comment: Is this compliant behavior?

Comment: Compliant with what? Have to say that the answer is around 9 years old, so it might be outdated :D

Comment: What about just adding #include <cmath>?

Comment: In response to @GabrieleCirulli's comment (from ages ago; sorry to @ you now!), I'd like to add that another way to find this out is to look at the man page for the function in question, and in particular the man page in section 3 of the manual -- i.e. type `man 3 floor` and/or `man 3 pow`, and they should each make mention of the `-lm` linker flag.

Comment: @KenIngram: that looks like a C++ version of the header... valid for C++, but a non-C++ C compiler will probably choke on it (`gcc` does, for me, though `g++` is just fine with it.)

Answer (score 27):

Add -lm to your link options, since pow() and floor() are part of the math library:

```
gcc fib.c -o fibo -lm
```

Answer (score 10):

For the benefit of anyone reading this later, you need to link against it as Fred said:

```
gcc fib.c -lm -o fibo
```

One good way to find out what library you need to link is by checking the man page if one exists. For example, `man pow` and `man floor` will both tell you:

Link with `-lm`.

An explanation for linking math library in C programming - [Linking in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Answer (score 9):

In regards to the answer provided by Fuzzy:

I actually had to do something slightly different.

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Libraries

Click the little green add icon, type m and hit ok. Everything in this window automatically has -l applied to it since it is a library.

Answer (score 7):

To find the point where to add the -lm in Eclipse-IDE is really horrible, so it took me some time.

If someone else also uses Edlipse, here's the way how to add the command:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Miscelleaneous -> Linker flags: in this field add the command -lm

Answer (score 4):

All answers above are incomplete, the problem here lies in linker `ld` rather than compiler `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. When you are compiling your `fib.c` to object:

```
$ gcc -c fib.c
$ nm fib.o
0000000000000028 T fibo
                 U floor
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U pow
                 U printf
```

Where `nm` lists symbols from object file. You can see that this was compiled without an error, but `pow`, `floor`, and `printf` functions have undefined references, now if I will try to link this to executable:

```
$ gcc fib.o
fib.o: In function `fibo':
fib.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `pow'
fib.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Im getting similar output you get. To solve that, I need to tell linker where to look for references to `pow`, and `floor`, for this purpose I will use linker `-l` flag with `m` which comes from `libm.so` library.

```
$ gcc fib.o -lm
$ nm a.out
0000000000201010 B __bss_start
0000000000201010 b completed.7697
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000201000 D __data_start
0000000000201000 W data_start
0000000000000620 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000006b0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200da0 t 
__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000201008 D __dso_handle
0000000000200da8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000201010 D _edata
0000000000201018 B _end
0000000000000722 T fibo
0000000000000804 T _fini
                 U floor@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000006f0 t frame_dummy
0000000000200d98 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000000009a4 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000200fa8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
000000000000083c r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000000588 T _init
0000000000200da0 t __init_array_end
0000000000200d98 t __init_array_start
0000000000000810 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000800 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000790 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000006fa T main
                 U pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000660 t register_tm_clones
00000000000005f0 T _start
0000000000201010 D __TMC_END__
```

You can now see, functions `pow`, `floor` are linked to `GLIBC_2.2.5`.

Parameters order is important too, unless your system is configured to use shared librares by default, my system is not, so when I issue:

```
$ gcc -lm fib.o
fib.o: In function `fibo':
fib.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `pow'
fib.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note `-lm` flag before object file. So in conclusion, add `-lm` flag after all other flags, and parameters, to be sure.