# C Programming: Virtual Computer

Tags: c

I am writing a c program for a virtual computer. The problem I am having right now is that when I try to compile, I get an error that says "undefined reference to 'pow'
I'm not sure how to change it correctly.

```
void memAssign(signed int *mem, char line[SIZE],signed int *memPos){
    signed int *count= &mem[73];
    signed int *length= &mem[74];
    *length = strlen(line)-1;
    *count=1;
    if(toDigit(line[*length-1])<0 || toDigit(line[*length-1])>9){
        printf("Wrong command form.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(line[*length - *count] != ' '){
        mem[*memPos] += (toDigit(line[*length - *count]) * (int)pow(10, *count - 1));
        *count += 1;
    }
    count = NULL;
    length = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you used `#include<math.h>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to \`pow' and \`floor'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor)

Answer (score 4):

While using the `math` library functions you have to include the header file `#include<math.h>`.
 And then while compiling you have to link that.

```
 cc filename.c -lm
```