# How to find -lm lib and include it in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am using CMake to build my project. It shows the error

> ./../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/lee/bin/ants/lib/libitkgdcmopenjp2-5.0.a(tcd.c.o): in function 'opj_tcd_init_encode_tile':
>   tcd.c:(.text+0x1d42): undefined reference to '__pow_finite'

I googled and it said that I have to include extra libs that is the math lib `lm`. I have tried two ways:

1. Build with `cmake CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-lm" ..` However, it is not work
2. Add `lm` in the CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(lm myprogram ${ITK_LIBRARIES})`. But it shows the error `Cannot specify link libraries for target "lm" which is not built by this  project.`

Could you tell me any suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
target_link_libraries(lm myprogram ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

[You got the order wrong](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). This asks to link `lm` with the libraries `libmyprogram` and whatever's contain in `ITK_LIBRARIES`.

---

Try:

```
target_link_libraries(myprogram m)
```

Which asks cmake to link `myprogram` with `libm`. This implies libm is installed in a system directory. If it is not, you must either:

- [`find_package(m)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) and then `target_link_libraries(myprogram ${M_LIBRARIES})`,
- or [provide CMake with the location of libm](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_directories.html).

Comment: Thanks YSC. I can build cmake sucessful but It show error in the make . I think we should add one command to find `lm` lib. This is error when run make `/home/lee/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -llm`

Comment: The name of the library is `m`. Therefore it is `target_link_libraries(myprogram m)`

Comment: The `l` (L) in `lm` is a part of the linker arguments syntax that is not necessary. `m` is the name of the library so for CMake `target_link_libraries(myprogram m ...)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816646/can-cmake-detect-if-i-need-to-link-to-libm-when-using-pow-in-c But it does not work.Note that, the libm is located at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6`