# How do I tell which of these ldd-reported libraries require allowance for via CMake?

Tags: cmake, libraries, dependency-management, idioms, libdl

Suppose I'm creating a target for an already-compiled library, `foo.so`. Now, this library has the following requirements/dependencies, as specified by `ldd`:

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77d4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf5de7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf5c0c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf5c07000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf5be8000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf5bde000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d5000)
```

I'm now wondering which packages I should have to look for and utilize as INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.

I'm assuing I need:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE Threads::Threads)
```

and also

```
target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE INTERFACE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}))
```

but what about all the rest of those items? For `rt`, I could write,for example

```
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE INTERFACE rt) # Not 100% sure this is necessary
endif()
```

should I? And what about the other libraries?

**Note**: I'm *not* asking for help determining what the right CMake package name is for these libraries. My question is, for each of them -  whether I should just ignore the fact that they're listed and hope that things will turn out alright, or - whether I should do something about them in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Each dependent library is represented by its own CMake package. There is **no universal rule** for deducing a package name from the library name. You have already found absence of such rule, which deduces `Threads` package from `libpthread.so` and plain `rt` library from `librt.so`. Well, there is a "rule" that for link with `libFoo.so` library one should specify `Foo` in the `target_link_libraries` call. But that rule is quite obvious. So, what do you want by asking such question?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I'm not asking about the translation. Suppose I know which of these libraries are represented by cmake packages and how to give the CMake command for linking against them, when they aren't. The question is: _should_ I do it. I'm mostly interested in these specific libraries (which are in very frequent use on Linux), but if you can say something more general, that would be nice too.

Comment: Needs for linking with `libm` are covered e.g. in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816646/can-cmake-detect-if-i-need-to-link-to-libm-when-using-pow-in-c). Needs for linking with `pthread` are covered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395309/how-do-i-force-cmake-to-include-pthread-option-during-compilation). Do you want to combine those questions into your own? This is generally a bad way to organize things on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: None of that answers my question, even when limited to just these libraries.

Comment: If the library uses only types it defines itself in its public interface then you don't need to link to anything but this one library. If it uses symbols from libc in the public interface (e.g. `time_t`) your project will also have to link to libc if you call such a function. To determine which libraries need to be in the INTERFACE link libraries you should not look at `ldd` output, but look at the public header files instead. Any library that is `#include`d there you'll have to add to the INTERFACE link libraries. librt, libdl and libpthread are unlikely to be among them.