# autotools - Fix undefined reference to `pow' and `floor'

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

An undefined reference to `pow` or `floor` is often caused by a missing or misplaced `-lm` option (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor)).

I saw this error in an [open source repository](https://github.com/Toyota-ITC-SSD/Software-Analysis-Benchmark) after running through the autotools workflow: `aclocal` `autoconf` `automake --add-missing` `./configure` `make`.

Here is the offending build command from the make output:

```
gcc -pthread -g -O2 -lm  -o 01_w_Defects bit_shift.o main.o buffer_overrun_dynamic.o memory_allocation_failure.o buffer_underrun_dynamic.o memory_leak.o cmp_funcadr.o not_return.o conflicting_cond.o null_pointer.o data_lost.o overrun_st.o data_overflow.o ow_memcpy.o data_underflow.o pow_related_errors.o dead_code.o ptr_subtraction.o dead_lock.o race_condition.o deletion_of_data_structure_sentinel.o redundant_cond.o double_free.o return_local.o double_lock.o sign_conv.o double_release.o sleep_lock.o endless_loop.o st_cross_thread_access.o free_nondynamic_allocated_memory.o st_overflow.o free_null_pointer.o stubs.o func_pointer.o st_underrun.o function_return_value_unchecked.o underrun_st.o improper_termination_of_block.o uninit_memory_access.o insign_code.o uninit_pointer.o invalid_extern_1.o uninit_var.o invalid_extern.o unlock_without_lock.o invalid_memory_access.o unused_var.o littlemem_st.o wrong_arguments_func_pointer.o livelock.o zero_division.o lock_never_unlock.o
```

As you can see, `-lm` comes before all of the files in the build command. It should come at the end. If I move `-lm` to the end and re-run the command, it works.

But this doesn't fix the root problem. What went wrong? Where should I look to find the issue or a potential fix? I imagine this issue could be fixed in either `Makefile.am` or `configure.ac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `-lm` as an `LDFLAGS` entry; it is not, it's instead a `LIBS` entry. The easy way to fix this is to avoid referencing `-lm` in `Makefile.am` at all and instead add to your `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pow], [m])
```

This way if `pow` is defined in the C library (rare but there are a few OSes where that happens) nothing will be added to `LIBS` whereas if it is defined in `libm`, `LIBS` will be set to `-lm`; since `LIBS` is passed after the list of files, the linking will work.

Further reference (written by me in the past): [Finding Libraries on Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/autoconf/finding.html), [`--as-needed` and linking order](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/As-needed#Importance_of_linking_order).

Comment: That works, thank you! Presumably one should do the same for floor? Looks like it's `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` with an `S`.

Comment: Thanks, I keep making that mistake ^^; And correct, you can do that for `floor` just as well, although I do not know of any C library in which `pow` and `floor` are on different libraries.