# Undefined reference for a specific library: FastNoiseSIMD

Tags: c++11, header, include, noise, lib

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to include a header file from this library, https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoiseSIMD

When I write this line, `FastNoiseSIMD* myNoise = FastNoiseSIMD::NewFastNoiseSIMD();` I get the error: `main.cpp:36: undefined reference to FastNoiseSIMD::NewFastNoiseSIMD(int)`

Here is how I'm including the header:

`#include "FastNoiseSIMD/FastNoiseSIMD/FastNoiseSIMD.h"`

As you can see, the files are in folders that are located in the working directory of my program. I'm working on Linux using c++11 and g++. I don't see any library files that I need to link so I'm stuck here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor?rq=1)

Comment: I understand that I would need a linker flag for a library, but if you look at the github page linked there is not a library file, only .h and .cpp.

Comment: @DevHeavy, actually I have read the documentation written in https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoiseSIMD/wiki/Compiler-Settings , but this does not says how they compiled and linked the lib. it just says what directives in the code should be used or removed for each compiler.