# How to build opencv that only support decode jpeg?

Tags: opencv, jpeg, decode

I just need to call `cv::imread("xxx.jpg")`, how can I compile the most simple lib of opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use other frameworks other than OpenCV. OpenCV is extremely heavy for this kind of job. It's mainly focused on image processing.

Maybe you can use OpenImageIO, [freeimage](https://products.fileformat.com/image/cpp/openimageio) or other libs.

You can refer to these posts:

[Reading an image file in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076475/reading-an-image-file-in-c-c)

https://products.fileformat.com/image/cpp/openimageio